# Pandas DataFrame - convert months to datetime and iteratively select data from multiple columns for plotting

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas DataFrame with the format:

```
     Month Thing1 Thing2       Tot
0   Jan-12      A      Z  0.005880
1   Jan-12      A      Z  0.024500
...
20  Jan-12      B      Y  0.001533
21  Jan-12      C      X  0.003892
22  Jan-12      C      X  0.001680
23  Jan-12      C      X  0.001680
24  Jan-12      C      X  0.001680
25  Jan-12      C      X  0.001680
26  Jan-12      A      W  0.001680
27  Jan-12      D      V  0.013440
28  Jan-12      E      U  0.001680
...
```

The Month column goes unitl Apr-14. I am trying to plot line graphs for the monthly totals for each item in `Thing1` and `Thing2`.

I am attempting this using `groupby`:

```
a=pd.read_csv('all2.csv')
sums=a.groupby([u'Month',u'Thing1',u'Thing2']).sum()
```

which gives me:

```
Apr-12 A      W         6.427773
              Z         4.347471
       B      T         7.062425
              Y        17.183562
       C      X        14.583337
       D      V         0.114450
       E      U         0.008050
       F      Q         0.000490
              R         0.004468
       G      P         0.010932
       ...
```

However the months come up alphabetically. My questions are:

How can I get Pandas to consider the month column as a datetime object?

How can I iterate through `Thing1` column and plot time series monthly totals for each item in `Thing2`?

I imagine there is a way to reorganise the Dataframe such that a simple call to `plot()` will do the job?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your 'Month' column is not in the right `dtype`. You can get the intended result by firstly converting the `Month` column to datetime format:

`df['Month']=pd.to_datetime(df.Month)`, before calling `df.groupby([u'Month',u'Thing1',u'Thing2']).sum()`

But careful, `Pandas` doesn't know whether `Jan-12` means `2014-01-12` or `2012-01`, by default it convert you data to the former. To get the latter, supply `.to_datetime` with `format='%b-%y'` argument.

For your second question, you can get the level of `Thing1` by `dfgb.index.get_level_values(1)`. where `dfgb` is the `DataFrame` from `groupby`. Then you can plot the time series by:

```
for item in dfgb.index.get_level_values(1):
    dfgb.xs(item, level=1).plot(kind='bar') #for bar graph
```